# Falling Box Question

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, drag

Let's say that I drop a 2D box which weighs mass *m* (lets say 10kg), in an infinitely large 2D space (+ time) which has gravity *g* (lets say 9.8), constantly pushing the box downwards, the space has 1ATM of pressure (lets say it's completely populated with hydrogen atoms), the box has rotation *θ* (let's say 35deg) and an initial angular velocity of zero.

My question is whether, after an infinite (or close to infinite) amount of time, what angle will the box settle into (The answer I guess would be 45deg off the top of my head but I don't know if there is a way of proving this)? Since its hitting the particles it eventually will reach an equilibrium where the box no longer rotates. Right?

So, is there maths we can do to find what the 3D rotation of the box approaches? Off the top of my head it probably has lots of partial derivatives and limits but I really don't know.

Apologies if this question is unsolvable.

Comment: In general the gas flow around a falling object will be turbulent and the object will tumble randomly instead of settling to a constant attitude. However I'm not sure how you would demonstrate this mathematically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any 2-dimensional hydrogen atoms to provide drag, so the specific formulation is a nonsense question.

However, we can promote the question to three dimensions plus time by restricting a cube to one axis of rotation. In that case, the drag coefficient of a cube is lowest (about 0.8) in its edge-on configuration. We get to skip all of the math because this is a well known empirical fact.

If the cube is initially not rotating and the gas is perfectly still, both the surface-on and edge-on conditions are equilibria at their respective terminal velocities. However, the surface-on condition is unstable. An angular displacement will cause its velocity to increase, increasing energy. Once increased, it will cost energy to restore the surface-on configuration. On the other hand, the edge-on configuration is stable. An angular displacement will force it to slow down, losing energy; restoring it to the edge-on configuration gives energy rather than costing any.

If the angle is initially other than surface-on or edge-on,  the shape of the cube is not symmetric about the vertical axis, so lift (from angle of attack) will cause the path of the cube to curve. Hence none of those orientations can be equilibria.

Of course real atmospheres have winds that vary with time and altitude, so there is no configuration that is *always* edge on to the flow, hence no equilibrium, if we get away from the toy model.